# Insert or update table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I want to insert new rows into a mysql table, but when same row already exists then update rows. So for example

```
`INSERT INTO table (character_id, data) VALUES(1212, "test")` WHEN character_id exist then UPDATE...
```

Any one know how to create sql query for this?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query to do this:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from demo where character_id=1212)
   update demo
       set character_id=123 and data='test'
       where id=1212
ELSE
   insert into demo (character_id, data)
       values(1212, "test");
```

More efficient way of doing this would be as suggested by juergen d in comment:

```sql
INSERT INTO demo (character_id, data)
VALUES(1212, "test")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE character_id=123 ,data='test'
```

**For Reference:** [MySQL Documentation-Insert-on-duplicate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Updated  the answer with an efficient way to do this